# Cannot filter the ids which have boolean value true inside the array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to filter those records ids that have `isPaymentCompleted: true` inside the `arr_object` but the condition is that the last object's boolean value must be false. All the other objects' boolean values must be actual if there is another false value inside the arr_object except the last one then that record's id won't be selected.
Is there any problem understanding my query please comment

I've tried multiple times but still, I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Please any one help me

### Here is the image of my database schema

[image]

I want only record ids, not the inside array object ids.

Comment: Would you show the queries you have tried and the problems with them?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I have updated my image actually I didn't see that I share actually an old image of database this is the new one please check

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/tracebacks/stacktraces/data/etc. - just copy/paste them into a code block.  You are looking for a MongoDB query, yes?  What queries have you tried?  What was wrong with your queries?

Comment: Also, please review your text.  It no longer corresponds to the example document you show.

Comment: @rickhg12hs ok thanks for the advice actually when I get the error actually I delete that block of code and then try a different method. But I figure out the code and I sharing my answer as well

Comment: @rickhg12hs I think there is a flaw in my code I checked `shouldPaidByAdmin` is true and date but I think I should check other objects as well because its true that `shouldPaidByAdmin` is true only in the last object when the date comes to the last object before that other objects `isPaymentDone`  will be true what if it wasn't true can you check

Comment: @rickhg12hs If you can improve the code

Comment: Your query seems to indicate that there are conditions on `dueDate` as well.  Would you update your question to include _**all**_ of the conditions that must be passed to return `"_id"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes in every object dueDate is extended by one month like if the user create a scheme today then the first object due date will today but the next object will be next month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer I figured to actually get that particular record I use the date object to match and another boolean called the `shouldBePaidByAdmin` object should true match then I will get the id

```
const year = new Date().getFullYear();
    const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;

    const numDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

    const monthNames = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
    ];

    const date = new Date(year, month - 1);

    // Create a new Date object for the start of the month
    const startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);

    const endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), numDays);

    //Get the ids of those objects that matches the condition

    const result = await PaymentScheme.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                paymentData: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        dueDate: {
                            $gte: startDate,
                            $lt: endDate,
                        },
                        shouldBePaidByAdmin: true,
                        isPaymentDone: false,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$paymentData",
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "paymentData.dueDate": {
                    $gte: startDate,
                    $lt: endDate,
                },
                "paymentData.shouldBePaidByAdmin": true,
                "paymentData.isPaymentDone": false,
            },
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$user",
                userIds: {
                    $push: "$_id",
                },
            },
        },
    ]);
```